# Cannot post an image to S3 using node.js aws-sdk

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to get a POST endpoint working with AWS, to post an image to an amazon bucket, but i'm getting the following error from s3fs/aws-sdk.

`Unhandled rejection MalformedXML: The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema`

Why is this error happening and how can it be fixed?

Here is my POST function amongst other relevant things:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import s3fs from 's3fs';
const S3FS = s3fs;

const s3fsImp = new S3FS('testbucket', {
  accessKeyId: 'asdf...',
  secretAccessKey: '1234...',
});

s3fsImp.create();

...

const file = req.files.file;
const stream = fs.createReadStream(file.path);
return s3fsImp.writeFile(file.originalFileName, stream).then(() => {
  fs.unlink(file.path, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
    res.json({ working: true });
  });
});
```

I find the error message quite useless because i'm not providing any XML. Do I need to declare/flag a schema somewhere or something? I don't understand why this is happening yet.

I'm testing this with Postman:

- no content type set
- sending image via body 'file' set as type 'file' (as apposed to 'text')
- plain `form-data`

I've been reading some documentation and tutorials and i'm now unsure how to continue with this. Any help is appreciated.